# Proof explanation: Sufficiency and maximum likelihood

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, maximum-likelihood

I was reading a book on mathematical statistics and came across the following statement.

> Suppose that the statistic $T(X)$ is sufficient for the parameter $\theta$. If $\hat\theta(X)$ is a maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$ **and $\hat\theta$ is unique** then it depends on $X%$ only through $T(X)$.

I assume that an argument can be given in the following way:

Let $X$ denote a random variable and $x$ its value.

$P_{\theta}(X)=P_{\theta}(X=x, T(X)=T(x))=P(X=x|T(X)=x)P_{\theta}(T(X)=x)$

The third equality follows directly from the sufficiency.  And clearly there is an equivalence between finding the maximum of $P_{\theta}(X)$ with respect to $\theta$ and the maximum of $P_{\theta}(T(X)=x)$.

**However**, I know something about the proof is wrong since I am not using the uniqueness, can anybody show me where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the proof is in wrong conclusions from the last phrase:

> *And clearly there is an equivalence between finding the maximum of $P_{\theta}(X)$ with respect to $\theta$ and the maximum of $P_{\theta}(T(X)=x)$.*

It does not imply that any $\theta$ that maximises $P_{\theta}(X)$ depends on $T(X)$. It implies only that *the set* of all values of $\theta$ which provide maximum of $P_{\theta}(X)$ depends on $T(X)$ only. And particular value of $\hat\theta$ among this set can possibly be chosen in such a way that it will depend on the sample itself.

For example, $X_i$ are Uniform $(\theta,\theta+1)$. Here $T(X)=(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ and MLE is any $\theta$ from the interval $X_{(n)}-1\leq \theta \leq X_{(1)}$.
Say, for $n\geq 2$ we can take
$$
\hat\theta = \frac{X_1^2}{X_1^2+X_2^2} (X_{(n)}-1) + \frac{X_2^2}{X_1^2+X_2^2} X_{(1)}
$$
Or 
$$
\hat\theta = \cos(X_1) (X_{(n)}-1) + (1-\cos(X_1)) X_{(1)}.
$$
It depends on $X$ not only through $T(X)$.

This was almost exact citation from Moore, D. S. (1971). Maximum Likelihood and Sufficient Statistics. The American Mathematical Monthly, 78(1), 50. doi:10.2307/2317488.

The paper containes three pages and completely devoted to your question.